# Calling principal does not have required MSGraph permissions

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-runbook

I have a Runbook (Automation Accounts) parsing AAD SignIn and Audit logs, however, when it executes Get-AzureADAuditSignInLogs I'm getting the following error:

```
`Get-AzureADAuditSignInLogs : Error occurred while executing GetAuditSignInLogs Code:     Authentication_MSGraphPermissionMissing Message: Calling principal does not have required MSGraph     permissions AuditLog.Read.All`
```

The Managed Identity I'm using in Runbook has Security Reader role, but it doesn't seem to be enough?

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/authenticate-azureps?view=azps-9.4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the same error when I checked in powershell:

[image]

> Note: ***The AuditLog.Read.All permission is an application permission
> which is part of  Microsoft Graph API and not a built-in role in Azure
> Active Directory (AAD).So it must be granted through an app in azure
> ad***

Create an app in azure ad tenant .For that app create client secret and certificate and note down secret value and certificate thumbprint for both

***Give the AuditLog.Read.All Api permissions  to it and grant admin consent .***

[image]

[image]

And then go to the azure automation account.
Access control IAM blade > add role assignment > security reader or Contributor role  to the application
[image]

Here I gave Owner role .

[image]

In automation account Add a credential button.
Enter  name and the service principal credentials which are "Application (client) ID" and the "Client Secret".

[image]

Then the script to run audit logs can be run successfully

[image]

```
$credential = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name "myrunbookcred"
Connect-AzureAD -TenantId "xxxxxxx" -ApplicationId "axxxxxxxx26 " -CertificateThumbprint "1C6BFB53xxxxxxxxxxx3CD401" -Credential $credential

Get-AzureADAuditSignInLogs
```

[image]